# The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: INT,STRING

Tags: parsing, token, antlr

Trying a simple Grammar on antlr. it should parse inputs such as L=[1,2,hello].
However, antlr is producing this error: **The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: INT,STRING**.Any Help?

```
  grammar List;
    decl: ID '=[' Inside1 ']'; // Declaration of a List. Example : L=[1,'hello']
    Inside1: (INT|STRING) Inside2| ; // First element in the List. Could be nothing
    Inside2:',' (INT|STRING) Inside2 | ; //

    ID:('0'..'Z')+;
    INT:('0'..'9')+;
    STRING:('a'..'Z')+;
```

EDIT: The updated Grammar. The error remains with INT Only.

```
grammar List;
decl: STRING '=[' Inside1 ']'; // Declaration of a List. Example : L=[1,'hello']
Inside1: (INT|'"'STRING'"') Inside2| ; // First element in the List. Could be nothing
Inside2:',' (INT|'"'STRING'"') Inside2 | ; //

STRING:('A'..'Z')+;
INT:('0'..'9')+;
```

Comment: Those ranges look very weird (except `'0'..'9'` - that one looks fine). What exactly do you want them to match? Do you not get an error message about the range `'a'..'Z'` being empty?

Answer (score 1):

Your `ID` pattern matches everything that would be matched by `INT` or `STRING`, making them irrelevant. I don't think that's what you want.

`ID` shouldn't match tokens starting with a digit; `42` is not an identifier. And your comment implies that `STRING` is intended to be a string literal (`'hello'`) but your lexical pattern makes no attempt to match `'`.

Comment: I see what you mean. First, I deleted the ID terminal. Replaced ID with STRING in decl. Second, I changed (INT|STRING) to (INT|'"' STRING '"'). However, it didn't work.

Comment: @hussein: (1) see @sepp2k's comment about your ranges. (2) Using `STRING` instead of `ID` doesn't stop it from matching 42. (3) A string literal is a token. It's a token which starts and ends with a quote and which can contain almost anything, not just letters and digits.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. However, I still don't get the exact meaning of this error. STRING 's range got fixed and it worked. INT's problem remains. Can you please clear things up?

Comment: @HusseinJaber The error means that anything that could be matched by `INT` will also be matched by `ID`. So if you have the input `42` for example, it will be matched by `ID`, not `INT`, because both rules match and the `ID` rule comes first. So there are no inputs for which you'd get an `INT` token, making the `INT` rule useless. What rici is saying is that you should define `ID` in such a way that it wouldn't match `42`, only `x42` etc. (the rule in most languages is that the first character in an identifier must not be a digit), so that the `INT` and `ID` rules no longer overlap.

Comment: @sepp2k This makes sense. However, I removed ID from the Grammar. You can check the updated code above

Comment: @HusseinJaber Your `Inside1` rule also matches anything that `INT` could match. That one and `Inside2` really shouldn't be lexer rules at all.

Comment: @sepp2k Just noticed Inside rules began with Uppercase letters. Changed them to lowercase and worked fine.